# How to resolve race conditions on debounced user input?

Tags: javascript

For example, say a page returns search results based on debounced user text.

How do you account for the case where an endpoint has a highly variable latency in which the second call can return before the first call.

E.g.

User is typing **"books and movies"** with a keyup debounce of 500ms

The user slightly pauses in the middle so the string is **"books"**, this triggers a search call.

The user continues typing and finishes, triggering the second call with **"books and movies".**

The second call returns first, populating the list based on **"books and movies"**.

Then the first call, which was delayed comes back and re-renders the list based on **"books"**.

The user sees only **"books"** and is confused.

The surefire way to solve this is with a button to manually trigger the call. I'd like to avoid this though so I've increased the debounce but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: Using sync ajax ? :)

Comment: you should only do the call when the debouce process ends. you can achieve that doing things in a syncronous way.

Comment: Do not use sync ajax. One option would be to tag each search request with the time it was initiated, and include that information in the response. You can then only populate the list if the response is "newer" than the previous response.

Comment: The timestamp method was going to be my backup options, but I'm wondering if this is a 'solved' issue given how common ajax calls on keyup are. Perhaps the endpoint flakiness prevents this type of UX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We suppose that you use jQuery to make ajax calls.

One solution is to use a pooling system: basically an array containing ajax requests.
Each time, a new request is emitted, you abort all request in the pool.
So you ensure that the last request made will be the only one that will end.

Here is the implementation of the pool:

```
jQuery.xhrPool = [];
jQuery.xhrPool.abortAll = function () {
    jQuery(this).each(function (idx, jqXHR) {
        jqXHR.abort();
    });
    jQuery.xhrPool.length = 0;
};
```

Here is an example on how to use it with the "search repository API" from GitHub (https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories):

```js
jQuery.xhrPool = [];
jQuery.xhrPool.abortAll = function () {
  jQuery(this).each(function (idx, jqXHR) {
    jqXHR.abort();
  });
  jQuery.xhrPool.length = 0;
};


$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#SearchField").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        // First we abort all other request
        jQuery.xhrPool.abortAll();
      
        $.ajax({
          url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
          method: "get",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          data: {
            q: request.term
          },
          beforeSend: function (jqXHR) {
            // Before sending the request we add it to the pool. 
            jQuery.xhrPool.push(jqXHR);
          },
          success: function(data) {
            var items = new Array();
            for(var i=0;i<data.data.items.length;i++)
            {
              items.push(data.data.items[i].name);
            }
            response(items);
          }
        });
      },
      minLength: 3,
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" >
<input type="text" id="SearchField" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript works synchronously so there is no possibility of race conditions if you write your code correctly.

I guess you are using ajax (ajax is supposed to be async, don't use sync ever, once you go sync, you can't go back) to get the query result. You are probably using some code like this:

```
var req=new XMLHttpRequest();


req.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (req.readyState==4){
        if (req.status==200){
            // Your callback here which shows autocomplete suggestions maybe?
        }
    }
}
```

Hold on to that `req` variable. So once you do a new request, you can simply discard the old request like:

```
req.onreadystatechange=null;
```

You can also [abort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort) the ajax request like:

```
req.abort();
```