# Which event to use for search input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a search field which collects a query and performs a search with an AJAX request. I'm having trouble finding the perfect javascript event to use to execute the search.

**oninput**
Using oninput, the AJAX request is fired multiple times, once for each character in the input field. So searching for '123' will perform three AJAX requests:

1. '1'
2. '12'
3. '123'

**onchange**
Using onchange is more efficient in that it only fires a single AJAX request, but it forces the user to change focus from the search field in order to fire.

Is there a javascript event that I can use to have the best of both worlds? I'm using a timeout delay of 1.5 seconds on search to give the user enough time to enter the search query. Ideally, I'd like to use a JS event like **oninput** that fires without requiring the field loses focus, but only fires once for the entire value rather than once for each character in the input field.

Maybe the answer is to use the **onchange** event and automatically lose focus after 1.5 seconds? This just seems hacky and also introduces a usability issue in that if the user wants to change the search query they would need to set focus on the search field again.

Comment: You should debounce `input` event using a timeout inside this handler

Comment: We're using https://github.com/AOEpeople/deferred-event-callback for debouncing, you might want to give it a try.

Comment: You should use `keypress` event and take a look to this answer about "debouncing" with pooling ajax request => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37105255/how-to-resolve-race-conditions-on-debounced-user-input/37154887#37154887

Comment: Isn't my timeout example the same thing as debouncing the input event? http://pastebin.com/MetyrzqQ

Comment: @JeffWalden `delayed_timeout !== timeout`...  You use `clearTimeout(delayed_timeout);` but set `timeout = setTimeout(function() {...}, 1500);`. That's a typo

Comment: @A.Wolff THANK YOU! Clearly I haven't had enough coffee this morning...

Comment: I would first focus on the experience you want the user to have. Are you providing autocomplete, is there a certain minimum number of characters that should be entered before autocomplete? Is pressing the enter key an appropriate flow for the search?  Then, I'd design the solution around that. You may end up using a combination of techniques and handlers to implement it - for example, debouncing, on return keypress, even a search button.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how you could do it, debouncing `input` event:

```
$('input[type=search]').on('input', function(){
   clearTimeout(this.delay);
   this.delay = setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(this.value);
      /* call ajax request here */
   }.bind(this), 800);
});
```

And for better UIX, you should bind `search` event too:

```
$('input[type=search]').on('search', function(){
   if(this.value){
     /* call ajax request here */
   }
});
```

See [-DEMO-](https://jsfiddle.net/benz3raj/)

Comment: Can you share why you would bind search? Wouldn't it get hit twice if you bind to both and from what I read search isn't available on all browsers so you wouldn't want to do just search

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to run a call, when the user clicks enter. It seems really naturally to click enter when you finish writing the word.

That code runs doYourStuff() when user clicks enter after he enters some data to searchBox.

```
    $("#searchBox").keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            doYourStuff();
        }
```

If you don't like the solution you can always add a small button with some fancy search icon and run call, when user clicks the button.